# find string in a very big single lined file

Tags: java

I have a file I need to read that's over 50gb large with all characters in one line.

Now comes the tricky part:
I have to split it on all double quote characters, find a substring (srsName) and get the element behind it which in a for loop over split substrings has the i+1 index ("value").

Question:
Are there some progressive search implementations or other methods that I could use instead of filling up my memory?

To simplify:
There are quite a lot of those srsName substrings inside the file but I need to read just one of those as all of them have the same value following them.

Something about the file:
It's a xml being prepared for a xsl transformation. I can't use a xslt that creates indentation because I need to do it with as little disk/memory usage as possible.

This is how the value presents itself inside the file.

```
<sometag:sometext srsName="value">
```

Comment: Why don't use use a real XML parser like SAX/StAX? Trying to parse XML by hand will only lead to pain (and false positives, false negatives, wrong encodings and missing character references. But mostly pain).

Comment: what is the expected length of "value" in your file?

Comment: Holy moly... a 50gb single lined file? Mind if I ask what it is? Also my guess would be regex, but that would require you to load the string into memory.

Comment: The length of "value" can vary from 1 to 16 characters.

Comment: It's an output file from a geological data processing program.

Comment: as @Joachim Sauer suggested, use SAX-based xml parser(rather than DOM-based as DOM-based will fall over on a 50GB file).

Comment: I'm thinking more of a few character long queue that would pop/push newly read characters and use a contains method to search for srsName in it.

Comment: As for using a parser I don't want to use one because the first xml tag takes 4.5gb of space and doesn't contain srsName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it like this:

```
String myBuff = "";
char charBuff;
while(myBuff.length()<30)myBuff+=(char)br.read();

charBuff=(char)br.read();
try{
  while(true){
    myBuff=myBuff.substring(1)+charBuff;
    if(myBuff.startsWith("srsName"))break;
    charBuff=(char)br.read();
  }
}
catch(Exception e){}
value = myBuff.split("\"")[1];
```

where br is my BufferedReader

Answer (score 2):

One way to speed up your search in a massive file is adapting a fast in-memory search algorithm to searching in a file.

One particularly fast algorithm is [Knuth–Morris–Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm): it looks at each character at most twice, and requires a small preprocessing step to construct the "jump table" that tells you to what position you should move to continue your search. That table is constructed in such a way as to not have you jump too far back, so you can do your search by keeping a small "search window" of your file in memory: since you are looking for a word of only seven characters, it is sufficient to keep only the last six characters in memory as your search progresses through the file.

Comment: In OP's case the first character and last character are unique and do not repeat in the middle of the string. This makes looking at each character only once (starting looking for matches only on `<` and then ditching the match and start a new one if you see another `<` or an unmatching character) a much simpler (and also more efficient) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a BufferedReader - http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

This would allow you to specify the number of characters to read in to memory at once using the read method.

Comment: I only use BufferedReaders, but your answer gave me an idea on how to complete what I need to do.